# how to fill text box using playwright module if input type="hidden"

Tags: python, automation, playwright-python

i am trying to fill the title text box

**i used**
page.locator('input[name="fname").fill("XYZ") but getting error.
waiting for selector

**tried:**
i tried multiple ways like xpath, title, name, etc. I am not getting a proper idea:
**actual HTML is:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8i5l.jpg)

Comment: Are you table so share the URL of the form? We could provide better help if we're able to reproduce the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and remove the extra dots. Instead, add your code, as formatted text (use the `{}` button), as [mcve]. As is, it's impossible to help you. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The name of the hidden field in your code is not `fname`.

```py
new_value = 'XYZ'

# To fill the visible field:
await page.get_by_label('First name: ').fill(new_value)

# To fill the invisible field, one option is to apply it with js inside the browser context:
await page.evaluate(f'document.getElementById("custId").setAttribute("value", "{new_value}")')
```